# How do I force [ngClass] to re-evaluate a function?

Tags: angular, ng-class

Angular v8. I have a tag that uses the [ngClass] directive. The expression calls a function. How do I get ngClass to re-evaluate said expression after conditions have changed? It only seems to be getting called once. The tag resides inside a ng-template element. e.g.

```
<ng-template let-file>
<div [ngClass]="{'primary-class' : 'isPrimary()'}">text</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: You could try `<div [class.primary-class]="isPrimary()">text</div>`. And check not to have the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: What does the isPrimary function do? is it a complex function or one that simply returns a value

Comment: you're enclosing the function in single quotes, remove it: `{'primary-class':isPrimary()}`, or take account the comment of Guiacomo

Answer (score 0):

I got it working shortly after posting. I removed the single quotes.